# ¿Cómo obtener una función dentro de onclick con jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo una función que recorre un Array, al llamarla en un evento input  llama y funciona la función, pero al llamarla en el evento click no toma la función.
Pregunta: ¿Saben cómo llamar una función en el evento click?

Comment: Hola, debes colocar el código con el que estas trabajando para tener una mejor idea de lo que pretendes hacer.

Comment: Lo intente pero me toca poner todo y tengo datos sensibles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pues sin más datos de tu problema no sé si esto pueda ayudarte:

```js
var contenedor = $("#contenedor");

//función
function miFuncion(){
    contenedor.html("<marquee behavior='alternate'>Hola, mundo</marquee>");
}
 
//pasar parámetros
function miOtraFuncion(event){
  contenedor.html(event.data.nombre+" "+event.data.apellido);
}

//button
$("#Btn").on( "click", miFuncion);

//button para pasar parámetros
$("#BtnPasar").click({nombre: "Juan", apellido: "Perez"}, miOtraFuncion);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="contenedor"></div>
<button id="Btn">Ejecuta algo</button>
<button id="BtnPasar">Pasar parámetros</button>
```

En este ejemplo creas un botón (button) y activas (mediante el evento click) la operación de la función miFuncion().

Edición: se incluye botón para pasar parámetros.

Comment: A esa funcion necesito pasarle parametros es posible?

Comment: Si, puedes pasar parámetros a una función.Edito la respuesta para que veas un ejemplo.

Comment: Es que no se porque no puedo comentar mi codigo acá el caso es que no me esta sirviendo el ejemplo tengo un codigo muy amplio mi función es así function calcular(valor,fecha){
alert(valor)
}
$(".plus").on('click',function(e){
      calcular(1,2); //No esta trayendo esta funcion ese es mi problema
})

Comment: Revisa el código.  function calcular(valor,fecha){ 
  alert(valor) 
  } 
  
  $("#plus").on('click',function(){ 
    calcular(1,2);
  });